# D3js extend the line(s) of a BarLine to fill the whole width of the chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, data-visualization

I need some help creating a BarLine chart with dates in the X axis. I’m going to try to explain as clear as I can what is happening but I don’t have a lot of experience in D3 so I might end up saying or obviously doing something wrong.

I'm using a `timeScale` to create the scale for the X axis using this pattern:

```
d3ScaleTime()
    .domain(d3Extent(data, ({ name }) => new Date(name)))
    .range([width / data.length / 1.8, width - width / data.length / 1.8]);
```

This part of the code (`width / data.length / 1.8`) is just a fix that I'm applying to get the correct range for the space available, otherwise the chart will look like this:

[image]

As you can see in the image above, the lateral bars are being drawn outside the bounds of the chart, even tho the ticks look kind of correct. That's why I apply the fix and after that the chart looks like this:

[image]

Now the position of the bars look right as well as the position of the ticks, but the start and the end of the path are missing so I have another problem. My solution for this is to take the path in the X axis and extend it using:

```
d3Select('.axis-x path.domain').attr('d', () => `M0,0.5V0.5H${width}`)
```

Nothing crazy is happening here but after extending the path I have an X axis that looks like this:

[image]

Now finally everything looks right so I can continue with the next part of the chart that is creating the lines of the BarLine chart.

I wasn't expecting everything to go smoothly from here, but I'm kind of stuck because when I draw the line I get a line that doesn't fill the entire width of the chart, because the `timeScale` is setting the start of the range in the middle of the bar thanks to the initial fix that I showed before (`width / data.length / 1.8`), as you can see in the next image:

[image]

Now I really need some help to fix this. It doesn't matter if I have to extend the line in the same way that I'm doing with the X axis path (something that I have no idea how to do) or maybe fixing some previous error that I'm missing to spot in my code.

**Note:** the whole code is quite large and modular to post it entirely here, but if you want to see anything just ask and I'll try to provide as much detail as I can with some updates.

Comment: Looks like your base SVG container set-up is incorrect.  The canonical way to do it is to create margins on the left and bottom of the SVG, then draw in a `g` thats translated by these margins.  Finally the axis are placed into the margin space.  [This is a good basic example of this set-up](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/bdf28027e0ce70bd132edc64f1dd7ea4)

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Mark. In fact I'm following the canonical way to defined the margins and the work as intended using no dates for the labels. The problem is related on how the timeScale creates the x axis putting the first value at the beginning of the line instead of where the middle of the bar should be.